# query.wait is not finishing

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

I am new with async methods in MVC C#, so I tried some examples from [This tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/async-query-and-save.aspx)

So I coded a class with a method for saving `creditcardtoken`

```
public  async Task<CreditCardToken> RegisterCardTokenAsync(CreditCardToken creditCardToken)
{
    if (creditCardToken == null) return null;
    creditCardToken.number = creditCardToken.maskedNumber;
    _dbContext.CreditCardToken.Add(creditCardToken);
    var saveChanges = await (_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync());
    if (saveChanges > 0) return creditCardToken;
    else return null;
}
```

My controller has a method that calls my `registerCardTokenAsync`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IngresarTargeta(CreditCardViewModel creditCardViewModel)
{
    //do something here....
    //do another thing....

    var query = MyClass.RegisterCardTokenAsync(creditCardToken);
    query.Wait();
 }
```

In theory we use `query.Wait()` to "wait" until the operation is finished. My problem is that in my database the `CreditCardToken` is saved, however, my application just freezes.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

As far as I know await is required when executing `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC/Web API fully support `async` and `await`. Make your actions async

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't synchronously wait on `async` calls, unless you are completely aware of the context, let `async` propagate .

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IngresarTargeta(CreditCardViewModel creditCardViewModel)
{
   var result = await MyClass.RegisterCardTokenAsync(creditCardToken)
```

**Here is why**

- The top-level method calls `RegisterCardTokenAsync` (within the ASP.NET context).
- `RegisterCardTokenAsync` starts the save changes by calling  `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` (still within the context).
- `SaveChangesAsync` returns an uncompleted `Task`, indicating the save is not complete.
- `RegisterCardTokenAsync` awaits the `Task` returned by `SaveChangesAsync`. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the `SaveChangesAsync` method later. `SaveChangesAsync` returns an uncompleted `Task`, indicating that the `SaveChangesAsync` method is not complete.
- The top-level method synchronously blocks on the `Task` returned by `SaveChangesAsync`. This blocks the context thread.

...

- Eventually, the `SaveChangesAsync` will complete. This completes the `Task` that was returned by `SaveChangesAsync`.
- The continuation for `RegisterCardTokenAsync` is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available (so it can execute in the context).

This results in a **deadlock**. The top-level method is blocking the context thread waiting for `RegisterCardTokenAsync` to complete, and `RegisterCardTokenAsync` is waiting for the context to be freed so it can complete.

Comment: I see, I did not know anything about this since I am new with async methods. I have a question please, is my RegisterCardTokenAsync fine? I mean,do I need to make any changes to it? or just leave it without changes?

Answer (score 4):

In theory you should make all functions asynchronous

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> IngresarTargeta(CreditCardViewModel creditCardViewModel)
{
    //do something here....
    //do another thing....

     var token = await MyClass.RegisterCardTokenAsync(creditCardToken);
     Ok(token);
 }
```

Very good resource: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Notice that in ASP.NET Core your code will work, because it don't use SynchronizationContext. But still would be wrong to block asynchronous methods.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does not have a synchronization context, so this should not deadlock. I think "my application just freezes" is not a definition of a deadlock

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, true only for ASP.NET Core, in traditional ASP.NET it will freeze. OP uses traditional, based on tutorial page.

Comment: It's been so long since I've last used traditional MVC... I'd probably have to test this